# Can I select every object in the scene that is touching the active object?

Tags: selection-tools

While in object mode, I would like to be able to select all the other objects in the scene that are touching or intersecting a given object. For example, if the active object was Suzanne, this hot key or technique would select all the yellow cubes in the scene instantly.

Is there such a technique? I know in this example it would be easy to select all the yellow cubes by hand, but in a more complex scene this becomes an issue.

Thanks for your help!

[image]

Comment: I'm not aware that such functionality existing in Blender, as far as I know. It might be possible to achieve this through python scripting, though I don't know enough about it to suggest anything.

Answer (score 6):

An addon to do that:

**For 2.79:**

[image]

It uses a BVH tree to check if meshes are overlapping. BVH trees are built from boundings at first step (presuming boundings are a box) then with bmesh (for the intersecting bounding objects).

Important though: the overlapping test will fail if meshes do not intersect. For instance a mesh which is entirely inside the active one will not be detected.

For information: using bmesh.transform to obtain object's coordinates in world is mush faster than a Python calculation.

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Select intersect active",
    "category": "Object",
}

import bpy
from mathutils import Vector
from mathutils.bvhtree import BVHTree
import bmesh
import time

#In this context, utility/debug function to check if bounding test are ok
def BoundingsToMesh( obj, scene ):
    name = obj.name + "_bounds"
    meshData = bpy.data.meshes.new( name )
    meshObj = bpy.data.objects.new( name, meshData )
    meshObj.matrix_world = obj.matrix_world.copy()

    meshObj.data.from_pydata( *BoundingsGeometry( obj ) )

    scene.objects.link( meshObj )

    return meshObj

#Create bounding geometry from an object
def BoundingsGeometry( obj ):
    verts = [Vector(co) for co in obj.bound_box]
    edges = []
    faces = [ (0,1,2,3), (4,5,1,0), (7,6,5,4), (3,2,6,7), (6,2,1,5), (7,4,0,3) ]
    return verts, edges, faces

#Translates bounding geometry in world coordinates
def BoundingsGeometryInWorld( obj ):
    verts, edges, faces = BoundingsGeometry( obj )
    return [obj.matrix_world * v for v in verts], edges, faces

#Get vertices and polygons from an object in world coordinates
def MeshGeometryInWorld( obj ):
    return [obj.matrix_world * v.co for v in obj.data.vertices], [], [p.vertices for p in obj.data.polygons]

#Create a BVH tree from bounding (world co)
def BVHFromBoundings( obj ):
    verts, edges, faces = BoundingsGeometryInWorld( obj )
    return BVHTree.FromPolygons( verts, faces )

#Create a BVH tree from mesh (world co)
def BVHFromMesh( obj ):
    verts, edges, faces = MeshGeometryInWorld( obj )
    return BVHTree.FromPolygons( verts, faces )

#Create a BVH tree from bmesh (world co)
def BVHFromBMesh( obj ):
    bm = bmesh.new()
    bm.from_mesh( obj.data )
    bm.transform( obj.matrix_world )
    result = BVHTree.FromBMesh( bm )
    del bm
    return result

#Test if a bvh tree overlap an object
def IntersectBVHObj( bvh, obj, toBvh ):
    objBvh = toBvh( obj )
    result = bvh.overlap( objBvh )
    del objBvh
    return result

#Test if two objects overlap
def IntersectObjObj( obj, others, toBvh ):
    objBvh = toBvh( obj )
    result = [other for other in others if IntersectBVHObj( objBvh, other, toBvh )]
    del objBvh
    return result

#Test if two objects overlap using boundings method
def IntersectBoundings( obj, others ):
    return IntersectObjObj( obj, others, BVHFromBoundings )

#Test if two objects overlap using mesh method
def IntersectMesh( obj, others ):
    return IntersectObjObj( obj, others, BVHFromMesh )

#Test if two objects overlap using bmesh method
def IntersectBMesh( obj, others ):
    return IntersectObjObj( obj, others, BVHFromBMesh )

#Select objects which overlap another one
def SelectIntersect( obj, scene, others, intersectBounding ):
    result = IntersectBoundings( obj, others )

    if intersectBounding == False:
        #startTime = time.time()
        #for i in range( 1000 ):
            result = IntersectBMesh( obj, result )
        #print( "elapsed", time.time() - startTime )

    for o in result:
        o.select = True

class SelectIntersectActive(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.select_intersect_active"
    bl_label = "Select intersect active"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    intersectBounding = bpy.props.BoolProperty(name="Intersect bounding", default=False)

    @classmethod 
    def poll(cls, context):
        scene = context.scene
        obj = scene.objects.active
        return obj and obj.type == 'MESH' and obj.mode == 'OBJECT'

    def execute(self, context):
        scene = context.scene
        obj = scene.objects.active

        #Keep only non selected objects (cumulative selection)
        SelectIntersect( obj, scene, [o for o in scene.objects if o.select == False and o != obj], self.intersectBounding )

        return {'FINISHED'}

def menu_func(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(SelectIntersectActive.bl_idname)

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SelectIntersectActive)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_select_object.append(menu_func)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ObjectCursorArray)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_select_object.remove(menu_func)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

[image]

**Update for 2.8:**

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Select intersect active",
    "category": "Object",
}

import bpy
from mathutils import Vector
from mathutils.bvhtree import BVHTree
import bmesh
import time

#In this context, utility/debug function to check if bounding test are ok
def BoundingsToMesh( obj, scene ):
    name = obj.name + "_bounds"
    meshData = bpy.data.meshes.new( name )
    meshObj = bpy.data.objects.new( name, meshData )
    meshObj.matrix_world = obj.matrix_world.copy()

    meshObj.data.from_pydata( *BoundingsGeometry( obj ) )

    scene.objects.link( meshObj )

    return meshObj

#Create bounding geometry from an object
def BoundingsGeometry( obj ):
    verts = [Vector(co) for co in obj.bound_box]
    edges = []
    faces = [ (0,1,2,3), (4,5,1,0), (7,6,5,4), (3,2,6,7), (6,2,1,5), (7,4,0,3) ]
    return verts, edges, faces

#Translates bounding geometry in world coordinates
def BoundingsGeometryInWorld( obj ):
    verts, edges, faces = BoundingsGeometry( obj )
    return [obj.matrix_world @ v for v in verts], edges, faces

#Get vertices and polygons from an object in world coordinates
def MeshGeometryInWorld( obj ):
    return [obj.matrix_world @ v.co for v in obj.data.vertices], [], [p.vertices for p in obj.data.polygons]

#Create a BVH tree from bounding (world co)
def BVHFromBoundings( obj ):
    verts, edges, faces = BoundingsGeometryInWorld( obj )
    return BVHTree.FromPolygons( verts, faces )

#Create a BVH tree from mesh (world co)
def BVHFromMesh( obj ):
    verts, edges, faces = MeshGeometryInWorld( obj )
    return BVHTree.FromPolygons( verts, faces )

#Create a BVH tree from bmesh (world co)
def BVHFromBMesh( obj ):
    bm = bmesh.new()
    bm.from_mesh( obj.data )
    bm.transform( obj.matrix_world )
    result = BVHTree.FromBMesh( bm )
    del bm
    return result

#Test if a bvh tree overlap an object
def IntersectBVHObj( bvh, obj, toBvh ):
    objBvh = toBvh( obj )
    result = bvh.overlap( objBvh )
    del objBvh
    return result

#Test if two objects overlap
def IntersectObjObj( obj, others, toBvh ):
    objBvh = toBvh( obj )
    result = [other for other in others if IntersectBVHObj( objBvh, other, toBvh )]
    del objBvh
    return result

#Test if two objects overlap using boundings method
def IntersectBoundings( obj, others ):
    return IntersectObjObj( obj, others, BVHFromBoundings )

#Test if two objects overlap using mesh method
def IntersectMesh( obj, others ):
    return IntersectObjObj( obj, others, BVHFromMesh )

#Test if two objects overlap using bmesh method
def IntersectBMesh( obj, others ):
    return IntersectObjObj( obj, others, BVHFromBMesh )

#Select objects which overlap another one
def SelectIntersect( obj, scene, others, intersectBounding ):
    result = IntersectBoundings( obj, others )

    if intersectBounding == False:
        #startTime = time.time()
        #for i in range( 1000 ):
            result = IntersectBMesh( obj, result )
        #print( "elapsed", time.time() - startTime )

    for o in result:
        o.select_set( True )

class SelectIntersectActive(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.select_intersect_active"
    bl_label = "Select intersect active"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    intersectBounding = bpy.props.BoolProperty(name="Intersect bounding", default=False)

    @classmethod 
    def poll(cls, context):
        scene = context.scene
        obj = context.active_object
        return obj and obj.type == 'MESH' and obj.mode == 'OBJECT'

    def execute(self, context):
        scene = context.scene
        obj = context.active_object

        #Keep only non selected objects (cumulative selection)
        SelectIntersect( obj, scene, [o for o in scene.objects if o.select_get() == False and o != obj], self.intersectBounding )

        return {'FINISHED'}

def menu_func(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(SelectIntersectActive.bl_idname)

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SelectIntersectActive)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_select_object.append(menu_func)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ObjectCursorArray)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_select_object.remove(menu_func)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Can you update this script for 2.8?  It says "object has no attribute active"

Comment: @lakerice, done