# Is there a python script to see which objects are intersecting?

Tags: python, scripting

I've been working on a plant with particles and want to convert the particles to objects and then delete the leaves that intersect. Is there anything that will find the objects?  FYI, I have tried another person's script from 2017 but it gave an error

```
    line 109, in poll
    AttributeError: 'bpy_prop_collection' object has no attribute 'active'

location: <unknown location>:-1
```

This is the link for the script: [Can I select every object in the scene that is touching the active object?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77471/can-i-select-every-object-in-the-scene-that-is-touching-the-active-object)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I select every object in the scene that is touching the active object?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77471/can-i-select-every-object-in-the-scene-that-is-touching-the-active-object)

Comment: Unfortunately not because it indeed only finds the objects that are touching the active object. What I am looking for is a way to find all the objects that are intersecting with each other, regardless of whether or not they are the currently selected object.

Comment: Well, I think the provided code is a base to start what you want to do. Why don't you try to improve it?

Comment: I don't know how to code :p but I could give it a shot

Comment: ok, but also, if often people are helping here, they can't "do it for you as you just ask"... sometimes it can happen... but... hope you understand.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. If I knew the answer, I wouldn't ask.  If I figure it out, I'll post it for everyone...not sure what you are implying here.

Comment: I'm implying that I don't have it in my pocket: need to spend time (for you) to have it. and don't always have this time or eventually find the subject interesting enough. Hope someone else will do for you.

Comment: Additionally for this purpose, I don't think this is the good way. Try softbodies instead. Blender should do the work for you.

Comment: Try softbodies... If particles are softbodies, they won't intersect.

Comment: OK sure that's a good idea.  I did try cloth with self-collisions but that didn't work.  I'll try soft bodies thanks