# Apply material color to target orbject when this object is touching ( or under) an other object

Tags: animation, scripting, materials, effects

I have a grid of "target" objects and an animated "effector" object passing over the grid of "target" objects.
I would like apply the "effector" material color to the "targets" only when the "targets" are inside the "effector".

how can i do that?

[image: here is my blender 3D view]

Comment: maybe you can work with a distance driver. let the color be controlled by a driver that depends on the distance between the drones and the effector and maybe there is a way to transfer this information to keyframes later... I don't know. good luck

Comment: That might be a good solution, but I'm going to do a python script instead. I’ll share it here when finished, if anyone’s interested

Answer (score 1):

you could do something with dynamic painting. at the physics property is a tap called dynamic paint, you can set the cube as a brush and the drones as the canvas. Then make the setting so they give an output for vertex colors, make sure that the canvas drys fast and then use the wet map. you can find the vertex colors in your material nodes and then use it as a mix map or whatever you want. the only problem is that you have to update the drones once in a while. 
hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for this answer, but i already know this solution but i can't use it. In fact i'm using blender as a drone ligth show planning software. I create the animation for X drones and I apply diffuse colors to them. Then i export the result with a script using "active_material.diffuse_color [RGB channel]"

So one drone which carry only one RGB LED can carry only one color. I need a methode to change the material color of the drones when touching an effector object.

In fact i have to do something like shown on this gif:

https://imgshare.io/image/effector-video.B0hcd

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

So i used and modified the Lemon's script given here : [[Can I select every object in the scene that is touching the active object?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77471/can-i-select-every-object-in-the-scene-that-is-touching-the-active-object][1])

Here is the modified script

```py
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector
from mathutils.bvhtree import BVHTree
import bmesh
import time

#Create bounding geometry from an object
def BoundingsGeometry( obj ):
    verts = [Vector(co) for co in obj.bound_box]
    edges = []
    faces = [ (0,1,2,3), (4,5,1,0), (7,6,5,4), (3,2,6,7), (6,2,1,5), (7,4,0,3) ]
    return verts, edges, faces

#Translates bounding geometry in world coordinates
def BoundingsGeometryInWorld( obj ):
    verts, edges, faces = BoundingsGeometry( obj )
    return [obj.matrix_world @ v for v in verts], edges, faces

#Create a BVH tree from bounding (world co)
def BVHFromBoundings( obj ):
    verts, edges, faces = BoundingsGeometryInWorld( obj )
    return BVHTree.FromPolygons( verts, faces )

#Test if a bvh tree overlap an object
def IntersectBVHObj( bvh, obj, toBvh ):
    objBvh = toBvh( obj )
    result = bvh.overlap( objBvh )
    del objBvh
    return result

#Test if two objects overlap
def IntersectObjObj( obj, others, toBvh ):
    objBvh = toBvh( obj )
    result = [other for other in others if IntersectBVHObj( objBvh, other, toBvh )]
    del objBvh
    return result

#Test if two objects overlap using boundings method
def IntersectBoundings( obj, others ):
    return IntersectObjObj( obj, others, BVHFromBoundings )

#colorise objects which overlap the effector object
def ColorizeIntersect( obj, scene, others, frame ):
    result = IntersectBoundings( obj, others )
    for o in result:
        #Keyfraying previous color at fram just before "impact"
        o.data.materials[0].keyframe_insert(data_path="diffuse_color", frame= frame - 1)
        #At "impact" change color and add a color keyframe. 
        o.data.materials[0].diffuse_color = (0,1,0,1)
        o.data.materials[0].keyframe_insert(data_path="diffuse_color", frame= frame)
        #Select the touching item
        o.select_set( True )

scene = bpy.context.scene
current_Frame = scene.frame_current
obj = bpy.context.active_object
for f in range(scene.frame_start, scene.frame_end):
    scene.frame_set(f)
    ColorizeIntersect( obj, scene, [o for o in scene.objects if o.select_get() == False and o != obj], f )

scene.frame_set(current_Frame)
```

[image]

But it doesn't exactly do what I want. It only changes the color of drone objects when it comes into contact with the surface of the object effector. I would like the drone objects to change color inside the effector object and resume their original color when they come out.

Any idea?